# What is the correct pd.to_datetime format for strings of the form '12/2/14 0:01'?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to convert the column 'DateTime' of my pandas df to DateTime format. The following doesn't work, how can I specify the format when my strings are of the form '12/2/14 0:01'?

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format='%m/%d/%YY %H:%M').dt.time
```

Better yet, can I simply break it apart into two separate columns for date and time?

Comment: `%m/%d/%y %H:%M`

Comment: @yatu Thanks, this doesn't give me errors but it ignores the time. The new column is just the date.

Comment: pd.to_datetime('12/2/14 0:01').time().strftime("%H:%M") does the job i guess

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant it ignores the date. 

@iamklaus that works as well but only for the time, the date is discarded.

Comment: you want the date or the the time, or both ?

Comment: @iamklaus ideally both, the times are the most important part so this solves it for me, but now I'm curious how do I get both.

Comment: pd.to_datetime('12/2/14 0:01').strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M") check this

Comment: @iamklaus Ah, that does it! If you post it as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
df['DateTime'] = df['DateTime'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M'))
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a syntax error: 

File "<ipython-input-301-4f0f74a8fef8>", line 2
    df['DateTime'] = df['DateTime'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, %m/%d/%y %H:%M))
                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: weird, it says that the module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: hmm another hikup it was supposed to be datetime.datetime.strptime(). This one always gets me :)

Comment: @that does it, although it excludes the time. Someone posted the answer with the time in the comments. If they don't post it as an answer I'll accept this one. Thanks!